# I can't run shell script

Tags: bash, docker, alpine-linux

I made a dockerfile that uses the latest alpine and copies test.sh to /src.

I run the container and open up the CLI window in docker. Its path is /src and if I enter command `ls` I get the test.sh file.

But when I try to run it by either running `test.sh` or `./test.s`h it states /bin/sh: .test.sh: not found.

I added `RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash` before setting WORKDIR in my Dockerfile.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine:latest

RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash

WORKDIR /src

COPY . .
```

**test.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Test"
```

Content of host directory:

- Dockerfile
- test.sh

Opened up the docker cli for the container and run:

```
chmod +x test.sh
```

Then run ls -l and got `-rwxr-xr-x` on the file. then tried to run:

```
/bin/sh: ./test.sh: not found
```

Comment: You sure you specified `./test.sh` and not `.test.sh`?

Comment: This needs reproducible info.

Comment: @konsolebox yes, I even tried its full path /src/test.sh. That and ./test.sh. As /bin/sh: ./test.sh

Comment: Try to give more details. If you can give us a reproducible environment which we can test, that would be great.

Comment: Is the file executable?

Comment: @konsolebox added more info

Comment: @cornuz how do I do that? should be working as-is?

Comment: Try `chmod +x test.sh` before you run it. This makes sure it is executable.

Comment: Aside from the missing executable rights (or maybe a wrong PATH, if you invoke it just by `test.sh`), please remove the _bash_ tag from your question, since there is no bash involved.

Comment: Another point: Doing just a `ls` does not reveal whether or not the script is executable. You would have to do a `ls -l`, or to get more details, a `stat test.sh`.

Comment: The other frequent cause of a problem like this on a Windows host is if the file has DOS line endings; that turns the shebang line into `#!/bin/sh^M` which doesn't map to an actual interpreter.

Comment: Dockerfile might also be in CRLF and maybe that affects the commands. What's the output of pwd and ls?

Comment: you need to troubleshoot this yourself. I suggest open the CLI and run these commands and show us the output: ``cd /src``, ``pwd``, ``ls -l``, ``cat /test.sh``, ``./test.sh``. You need to be sure the file is where you think it is, has the permissions it needs and has the contents you want.